# extern declared template specialized function not found

Tags: c++, linker-errors

i'm trying to implement a clone of the json serialization library nlohmann::json as a learning experience, and i'm having trouble with the interface for user defined (json<->User type) conversion.

Basically i want the user to be able to overload two function: to_json(json&, const Type&) and from_json(const json&, Type&). Then the library will use overload resolution to call theses function in the templated operator= and one argument constructor.

It works fine when i'm just defining theses function directly but when i try to make a template definition for multiple types (in this example the class S) the linker can't find the definition.

I've tried to explicitly instantiate the function for individual instances of the templated class although i would prefer avoiding having to do that in the final product.

I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that templated function don't have the same signature than free function, but i don't see what i can do to make it work. What am i missing ? I also couldn't find result on google so is it a documented pattern or an anti pattern ?

Thanks you. Below i tried to minimize my problem in one short example.

Class.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdio>

template<size_t i>
class S {
    size_t n = i;
};

template<size_t i>
void g(const S<i>& s) {
    printf("S<%u>\n", i);
}
```

Class.cpp

```
#include "Class.hpp"

template void g<10>(const S<10>&); // <-- Even with explicitly instanciation

void g(const bool& b) {
    printf("%s\n", b ? "true" : "false");
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Class.hpp"

template<typename T>
void f(T t) {
    extern void g(const T&);
    g(t);
}

int main(int, char**) {
    S<10> s;
    //f(s); <-- linker error: void g(class S<10> const &) not found.
    f(false);
}
```

Comment: It's `extern template void g<10>(const T&);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name lookup for `g` in `g(t)` call stops as soon as it finds `extern void g(const T&);` declaration; it never sees the declaration of the function template. So the compiler generates a call to a regular non-template function named `g` taking `const S<10>&`. But no such function is defined in your program - hence linker error.

Comment: Why it stops on finding extern void g(const T&)

Comment: Ok, i see the problem, i see why then the original library require that theses function need to be available and in the same namespace than the user type.

Comment: @Kapil Because that's how unqualified name lookup works in C++ - from the smallest enclosing scope outwards, stopping as soon as the name is found.